# Can we calculate digit sum of $2x$ ($x \in N$) if we already know digit sum of $x$ and $x \equiv K \mod 10$?

Tags: number-theory

While trying to solve a programming problem, I'm stuck with this.

Let $f(x)$ to be sum of digit of $x$ and $x \in N$ (example $f(12334)=1+2+3+3+4=13$).

Can we calculate $f(2\cdot x)$ if we already know sum $f(x)=D$ and $x \equiv K \mod 10$ ?

If we can't, what information need to be added ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this works for $\pmod{9}$ but does not work for $\pmod{10}$.  That is, there is a one to one correspondence between the sum of the digits $\pmod{9}$ and the original number $\pmod{9}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am not clear with your comment, can you describe it in more detail.

Comment: See [Wikipedia - Casting out 9's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines) including its *Digital Roots* section.

Answer (score 1):

$f(2x)$ is not uniquely determined by $f(x)$ and $x \bmod 10$. Here is a counterexample: $12334$ and $1804$ both have last digit $4$ and digit sum $13$, but $f(2\cdot 1804) = f(3608) = 17$, while $f(2\cdot 12334) = f(24668) = 26$.

I do not know if you can reduce the amount of information you need; I think in general you need all the digits of $x$ in order to compute the digit sum of $2x$.

Examining the counterexample above, you can see what went wrong: $2 \cdot 1804 = 1804 + 1804$, and summing the $8$ to itself induces a carry $1$ into the 4th position. If you simply doubled each digit, you would get $26 = $ twice the sum of the digits of $1804$. But because of the carry, one of the $8$s is deleted out of the sum and replaced by a $1$.

So maybe there is a way to optimize after all: you need to know how many digits are $\geq 6$ (which would induce a carry $1$), and what each of those digits is (to correctly reduce the naive "double the digit sum" by). But if you try to iterate this and compute $f(4x)$ off of $f(2x)$, I do not think it will work without first needing to compute the digits of $2x$ anyway.